# How can I comapre two of the following objects?

Tags: c++, data-structures, set, operators

I'm trying to solve the 9-tile puzzle with the DFS/BFS (let's focus on the DFS as those two are basically the same) algorithm, and after some debugging I concluded why my code doesn't work.

I'm implementing the algorithm using a stack for the frontier, and a set for the closed set, and at some point I have to check if an object exists in the closed set. So naturally I use (temp is a 9-tile object):

```
if (closed.find(temp) == closed.end()){ 
\\do stuff
}
```

As I was trying to come out with this expression, I have learnt that I had to overload the '<' and '>' operators so that set.find() can work. So reaching my problem, the 9-tile objects are basically a 2d 3x3 array of integers, with 
the value 0 where the empty tile is. How can I determine if, for example, one of the following states of my board are "greater" or "smaller" than the other?

```
6 7 1   3 6 0
0 3 2   2 8 4
4 5 6   5 1 7
```

I have tried comparing each element with the final state which is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 0
```

Adding one point for each tile that is the same as in the final but it doesn't work, obviously because two boards with completely incorrectly placed tiles will have the same score, so I cannot compare them.

I have also tried going through the elements of two boards, and composing scores like this:

```
bool operator < (const Board &A, const Board &B){
    int scoreA=0, scoreB=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            scoreA += i * j * A.getTile(i, j);
            scoreB += i * j * B.getTile(i, j);
        }
    }
    return scoreA < scoreB;
}
```

However I'm not positive that this is correct, as I don't get the results I want.

Can you propose a better method of comparing two boards like this?

Comment: in `scoreB` you add also the values of tile `A`

Comment: note that `operator<` to be compatible with most algorithms is required to implement a strict weak ordering, not sure, but I couldnt convince myself that this is the case for your `operator<`

Comment: @Thomaslang that was a typo on my question, sorry about that. It's correct in my code. I'll edit it.

Comment: why not simple lexicographical order? Ie comare single elements in order, once you find one that is not equal in both you know which is smaller/bigger

Comment: You can add a hash function and use a `std::unordered_set`

Comment: If order isn't something that makes sense for your `T`, consider using an `std::unordered_set` instead. I can't recall precisely how this affects the complexity of DFS, but I doubt it matters for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try making an integer from the board such as

`1 2 3
 4 5 6  = 123456780
 7 8 0`

or in any pattern you'd like more.

This way, you don't have to compare the boards, only integer representations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solutions works, but for some reason both in my DFS and BFS implementations Clion pops me a bad allocation error. The answer I picked as correct gives me a result in BFS, while DFS still remains unsolved :-P.

Comment: CORRECTION - It works just fine with the BFS as well, I forgot to change some parameters and your method wasn't used. Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your variables which you compare are scores, I assume you want to do the comparison to check which board is closer to the solution of the tile moving problem.

In this case, you have to define some function `double calculateScore(const Board& board)` and then do a comparison:

```
double calculateScore(const Board& board)
{
  double score = 0.0;
  // as you wrote: adding one point for each tile that is the same as in the final 
  return score;
}

bool operator<(const Board& lhs, const Board& rhs)
{
  return calculateScore(lhs) < calculateScore(rhs);
}
```

Your goal is then to take the board that maximizes that score.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using BFS/DFS, it doesn't matter which elements are 'greater' or 'less'.  You just need the ordering to be consistent (if  a < b and b < c, then a < c), and whenever two boards are different you need one to be less than the other.

A lexographic comparison of the tiles suffices.  Something like this:

```
bool operator < (const Board &A, const Board &B){

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            int aTile = A.getTile(i,j);
            int bTile = B.getTile(i,j);
            if (aTile != bTile) {
                return (aTile<bTile);
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //equal
}
```

Note that this will work just fine, but it will be faster to use `unordered_set`.

Also, since you'll be creating so many boards, it would be nice to use a smaller representation.  If you pack them into an `int` as another poster suggest, then you can compare them with standard `<`.  If you pack them into a byte array, you can use `memcmp`.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! Your solution works on BFS with 148777 repetitions of my code, and it gives me a correct result! Clion however interrupts the program and gives me a bad allocation error on DFS at around 11k reps. However BFS works fine, so your solution definitely is correct!